# Replace Paragraph Return with space

Tags: regex, ms-word, wildcard

I have a document and I want to replace all the paragraph return with the space.

[image: Replace Paragraph Return with Space]

I tried to replace it with space but unfortunately it did wrong like in the attache image it found space and A in search and it replace it with space nd. 
What happened is that heaven." "
And 
is replaced by  heaven. nd
But I want it to be 
heaven." "And

Comment: Try `(^013)([a-zA-Z])` and replace with `" \2"` (space + `\2`)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for your help you saved my time :)
Do you have any idea how to Delete all * in the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MS Word Search and Replace, you may use groups and refer to their captured contents via backreferences like `\1`, `\2`, etc.

So, if you want to match a paragraph break that is followed with an ASCII letter, you need to use

```
^013([A-Za-z])
```

and replace with  `\1` (a space + `\1`, where `\1` inserts the letter).

To find and replace `*` you can just use a normal replacing mode (uncheck *Wildcard* option).  If you need to use `*` as a literal symbol in the wildcard pattern, put it into a `[]`: `[*]`.

Comment: One more thing I want to ask: "Look at the font size and typeface for the words "The Creation" and "The Creation of Man and Woman" Search for all items in that typeface and size and delete them."
How to do this one?

Comment: I have checked the Font Type: Helvetica and Font Size: 9.5

Comment: I have a problem with this "Search for all items in that typeface and size and delete them" I have seen option of formatting while using the wildcards but don't know how to do it.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you mean. I guess you need to replace some text with specific formatting only. You might need to click the *Formatting* button at the left-hand bottom corner and check the options there.

Comment: Actully I want to delete all the words having the specific formatting

Comment: That sounds like a completely different question. I think you hould post another one with your efforts.